# wordpress custom login form admin_post_add_ not working on live server but works on xampp

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a custom login plugin which uses:

```
$config = file_Get_content("somet path");
add_action('admin_post_add_members_login', array(new Members($config), "init"));
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_add_members_login', array(new Members($config), "init"));
```

**NOTE:** HTML Page has input type hidden action value="members_login"

This all works fine locally on xampp but on the live server, which is a typical cpanel linux server, it just redirects me to the wp-login.php page.

I switched it to following: (tried both functions in string and inline function):

```
function doit1(){
    error_log(json_encode("Hook 1 run"));
}

function doit2(){
    error_log(json_encode("Hook 2 run"));
}

add_action('admin_post_add_members_login', function(){
    error_log(json_encode("Hook 1 run"));
});
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_add_members_login', function(){
    error_log(json_encode("Hook 2 run"));
});
error_log(json_encode("Hooks registered"));
```

The error log will have "Hooks registered" on both local and live servers but the live server never logs "Hook 1 run" or "Hook 2 run", but the local xampp server logs everything fine.

PHP Version 7.4.7 on xampp and version 7.4 on live server.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On xampp creating action hooks for logged in and non-logged in users will work with no error, I didn't spend time tracing back through wordpress to find out why. When replicating the site on a local installation of ubuntu the issue was present, so either dual boot into ubuntu or use a VM and work on the issue there, saving screwing around with the live server all the time.

Login

1. Removed code in plugin so it just outputs the form on shortcode.
2. Reworked login via theme using:
   add_action('login_form', 'x'); // Add custom fields in fn x
   add_action('wp_authenticate_user', 'x'); // Validate & redirect login in fn x

Register

1. Removed code in plugin so it just outputs the form on shortcode.
2. Created custom php script to handle all I needed and set form action to post to that instead.